# How to get the height of a label with random text --kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, label, height

I wanted to get the height of the label that has its size_hint set to `(1,None)` .This is important for me. i actually want to update the boxlayout's height with it. so any help is apperciated.

```
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Label_(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout(size_hint = (1,None) , orientation = 'vertical')
        box.height = 0
        lbl = MDLabel(text = """A delivery truck takes 4.5 rosehorums to get from its warehouse in Garden City to the customer in Floralville at a speed of 50 PPP (poppyomiscusÂ per petuniaminium) and uses 10 cedariters of special Milorganine fuel during the trip.

How many pansyometers are travelled between warehouse and customer and what is the driverÂs fuel mileage in poppyomiscusÂ per marigoldetum? """,
                      size_hint = (1,None)
                      )

        print(lbl.height , lbl.text_size , lbl.texture_size)
        
        box.add_widget(lbl)
        box.height += lbl.height

        return box

Label_().run()
```

Here the height is fixed to 100. i think its a default height.
and i have tried using texture_size[1] , text_size[1] but it didn't worked.

So i actually want the actual height.

Just don't focus on label's text !!. I have randomly picked it.

and any help is apperciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

What you have is the correct way to access the height. One problem you have is that you don't want this instantaneous value, but a later value once the label has finished rendering.

Another problem you have is that the label height will always be 100 because you haven't done anything to cause it to take a different value.

The ideal solution is to set up bindings to update the things you want when their dependencies change. `BoxLayout` has a `minimum_height` property to make this easy. You want something like `box.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))`, and for the label `lbl.bind(texture_size=lambda instance, (width, height): setattr(lbl, "height", height))` (or in practice don't use a one-line lambda, write a function for it or even better use kv language which sets this up automatically.

Comment: Bro thanks. and sorry for late reply !!.  Bro can u just explain me what does `setter` does in the bind function? . And also please explain the bind function of the label .

Comment: Bro i got an unexpected error it seems .




SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```
And in pycharm when i move the cursor near the red line `(width, height)` it shows that `tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python 3`

Comment: Then fix the things it says are wrong. If you don't understand them after trying to investigate, ask a new question about them or give full details here.

Comment: The tuple parameter unpacking refers to `(width, height)`: replace this with `size` and then replace the reference to height with `size[1]`. Or, as I said in the answer body, write a proper function for this.